# Connection timeout error for vagrant up

Tags: ssh, vagrant, chef

I have Installed virtualbox-dkms

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
DKMS: install completed.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                              [ OK ]
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                              [ OK ]
Setting up virtualbox (4.3.34-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                              [ OK ]
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                              [ OK ]
Setting up virtualbox-qt (4.3.34-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...


$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'lucid32'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: chef-repo_default_1449661717604_69994
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

Comment: Can you successfully bring the box up using the virtaulbox gui (VirtualBox on my ubuntu desktop)?

Comment: $ vagrant init
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

Comment: ashishk@chef-workstation:~$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: base
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /home/ashishk/base

Comment: @Disco3 Box is successfully up